# Android application for quickly creating geo links

Tags: android, gps, hyperlink

Is there an Android app to create a simple geo link?

I just want:

1. button on the homescreen or menu
2. click it
3. get a link to gmaps, osm or [Geo URIscheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) (like `geo:37.786971,-122.399677`) in your clipboard or share function

Most messengers (WhatsApp) allow you to send an image from Google Maps, which often takes a long time (bad connection) and can't be used automatically in your communications partners navigation system.

This function is included in most navigation systems, but I don't want to launch my navigation app just to send 50 bytes of coordinates. OsmAnd offers this perfect:

```
geo:37.786971,22.399677
http://osmand.net/go?lat=37.786971&lon=22.399677&z=17
```

Comment: Several actually. As I've not tried any of them, I cannot give a clear recommendation – but be welcome to [check this list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_sharefake#group_565). Several of them might use the "share icon"; if you share to anything using text (e.g. SMS or mail), you should get a GeoLink.